# Not able enable /disable the form elements on grails page

Tags: jquery, html, templates, grails

I have mulitple forms  and button on a single grails page - 
What I want is to hide and show the differnt forms on the page using the enable button using jquery.

I tried using ID selectors but it enables all the forms which are there on grails page. Let me explain bit more.

I have template which gets excuted in for loop and this template has the form which has same id for all the forms but if i make the formid unique than how i am going get that unique for button click. What i want is that whenever user enters new comment, its gets appended to the "ALLCOMMENTS" div tag .This whole code is 4-5 times on one page. I apoligize for not including source code. This code is specific to the grails if anybody is working on grails app.

```
<div id="allcomments"></div>
<div id="newComment">
<input type="button" id="enableComment" value ="Comment"  class="enableComments"/>
<g:form action="addCommentToIsssues">
<g:hiddenField name="issueId" value="${myIssue.id}" />
<g:textArea id='postContent' name="comment"/><br/>
<g:submitToRemote class="myCommentButton" id="testingid"  name="testingpost" value="Post"   on404="alert('not found!')" 
                  url="[controller:'myIssue', action:'addCommentByAjax']"
                  update="[success: 'ALLCOMMENTS',failure: 'errorFP']"
                  onSuccess="clearComment(e)"
                  onComplete="updateDiv(e)"
                  />
</g:form>
<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you include some code that you're using, specifically to do the selections in jQuery?

Comment: My guess is: you have multiple elements with the same `ID`. `ID` should  and must be **unique**. When `id` isn't unique you can't forecast the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you've given all the forms the same ID, so that when you do `$('#myFormID').show()` or `$('#myFormID').hide()` all the forms are shown/hidden.

Instead give each form a unique ID, and pass the ID(s) of the form(s) you want shown/hidden to the JQuery selector instead, e.g. `$('#form1, #form2').show()`